# Flutter Firebase ListView - Slow Refreshes

Tags: firebase, listview, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, sqflite

I created a ListView that populates from a Firebase collection by using a StreamBuilder widget. It takes some time for the ListView to populate because I'm running tasks (HTTP requests) for each item of the Firebase collection and then displaying the result in the list.

When I navigate away from the page with the ListView and then return to the page (using PageView), the ListView appears to refresh entirely instead of using the last seen version. So there is a ~5 second circular progress indicator while the list re-populates every time the page is re-opened.

Questions:

- What is the best way to make this ListView not complete a full 5
  second refresh every time the page is re-opened? Can it use the last seen version and only update when items are added to the firebase collection?
- If I were to remove the tasks (HTTP requests) that need to be ran on each item of the collection and instead simply show values directly from the Firebase collection, should the refresh time be fast enough that it is not a problem?
- Is it best to create a local database (using sqflite) that syncs with the Firebase collection to prevent slow refreshes?

Code:

```dart
class AccountsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AccountsPageState createState() => _AccountsPageState();
}

class _AccountsPageState extends State<AccountsPage> {
  User user;

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document, String uuid) {

    // get data from firebase
    String token = document.data.values.toList()[0];

    // For current document/token, make an HTTP request using the token and return relevant data
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: FutureBuilder(
          future: anHTTPrequest(token, uuid),
          builder: (context, projectSnap) {
            if (projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none ||
                !projectSnap.hasData || projectSnap.data.length == 0) {
              return Container();
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: projectSnap.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(projectSnap.data[index]),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      )],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final container = StateContainer.of(context);
    user = container.user;
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: Provider.of(context).collectionRef.document(user.uuid).collection('tokens').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if (!snapshot.hasData){
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("No data")
                      )
                    );
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    reverse: false,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index], user.uuid);
                    }
                  );        
                }
              )

            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```